# Display column name based on status 0 or 1

Tags: sql, dynamic, sql-server-2012, conditional-statements

I don't understand how to achieve column name based on status, I think it's not possible to display multiple column names for the same but I have this requirement to display column name either 'Success' or 'Fail' and both status never be fetched, I have to select only one at a time either 0 or 1 based on where condition, value is defined in the variable.

```
CREATE TABLE #sqlJobHistory(jobId INT, jobStatus INT)
INSERT INTO #sqlJobHistory VALUES 
(1, 0),
(2, 0),
(3, 1),
(4, 1),
(5, 1),
(6, 0),
(7, 1)
```

I want to display my second column name based on status, So far I tried the commented line but :(

```
SELECT MAX(jobId) maxJobId, 
    COUNT(*) AS 'Failure' --AS CASE WHEN jobStatus = 0 THEN 'Fail' ELSE 'Success' END 
FROM #sqlJobHistory 
WHERE jobStatus = 0 
GROUP BY jobStatus
```

Can you please help he what's the proper way of achieving the desired output if it is possible, if not possible then extremely sorry for wasting your valuable time.

Comment: Can you be more specific what you want to achieve? E.g. the exact output?

In principle, I don't think it's possible to have a column name depend on some data-dependent condition.

Comment: @MarcinZukowski I think he wants second column name as 'Success' what status = 1 or 'Fail' when status = 0

Comment: Yes I exactly want so,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it can be possible through dynamic query, if I understand correctly, your second column name is 'Success' if Status = 1 else 'Fail'

```
DECLARE @status INT, @sql VARCHAR(500)
SET @status = 1 --It can be 0 or 1 and I think you already have this variable

SET @sql ='
    SELECT MAX(jobId) maxJobId, 
    COUNT(*) AS ' + 
    CASE WHEN CAST(@status AS VARCHAR)= 0 THEN 'Failure' ELSE 'Success' END + '
FROM #sqlJobHistory 
WHERE jobStatus = ''' + CAST(@status AS VARCHAR) + '''
GROUP BY jobStatus'

EXEC(@sql)
```